# I want to update the form value of Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Creating personal information registration form.
First enter the zip code and search.
If the address is found, the text is automatically entered in the form below.

However, I don't know how to automatically add an address to a text form after searching.

[image: IMG]

I got an address from a zip code. That data is stored in the properties of the personal information class.

The value of initialValue of FormBuilderTextField was changed using setState (). But it failed.

The value of `_formKey.currentState.value['prefectures'],` of `final GlobalKey<FormBuilderState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormBuilderState>();` has been changed. But failed

```dart
Widget inputFormWidget(
    String attribute,
    String hintText,
    String labelText,
    dynamic validate,
    String initialValue,
  ) {
    return Container(
      width: 260,
      child: FormBuilderTextField(
        attribute: attribute,
        initialValue: initialValue,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: hintText,
          labelText: labelText,
        ),
        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
        validators: validate,
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: google for TextEditingController, forexample https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/text-field-changes

Comment: Did you find solution ?

Answer (score 0):

To change the value programatically of FormBuilderTextField, you can use the following code:

```
_formKey.currentState!.patchValue({'zipcode_attribute': zipcode});
```

It's the way I'm doing on these cases and has been working well.